How can I solve to a closed form of the sequence $c_n=-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{n-k-1}a_{k+1}$, with $c_0=1$?
I was studying some things, and I’m stumped with the sequence $$c_n=-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{n-k-1}a_{k+1}, \quad c_0=1$$ Does it have a closed form?
I know it needs to have, because we can see by inspecting it: $$c_0=1, \quad c_1=a_1, \quad c_2=-\frac{1}{2}a_1^2+\frac{1}{2}a_2, \quad c_3=\frac{1}{6}a_1^3-\frac{1}{2}a_1a_2-\frac{1}{3}a_3$$
if we define the weight of every $a_n^m$ being $mn$, then if we sum the weight of all $a_n$ in all terms of $c_n$, it will sum m. For example: $c_1 \rightarrow a_1 \rightarrow 1; c_2\rightarrow a_1^2 //a_2 \rightarrow2;$ etc. And, we can see that the coefficient of $a_1^n$ in $c_n$ is $\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n!}$ and the coefficient of $a_n$ in $c_n$ is $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ (here for $n\geq2$)
EDIT: Some additional things (see the answers below)
Then, if $f(x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\dfrac{x}{x_n}\right)$, it can be expanded as a Maclaurin series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{B_n(-0!p_1,-1!p_2,\cdots,-(n-1)!p_n)}{n!}x^n$, where $p_n=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x_i^n}$.
If we relate to Weierstrass Factorization Theorem, we have that: $$f(x)=x^me^{P(x)}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\dfrac{x}{x_n}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n \iff$$ $$\iff c_n=\frac{1}{n-m}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[\frac{P^{(k)}(0)}{(k-1)!}-\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x_m^k}\right]c_{n-k}$$ where $c_0=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}x^me^{P(x)}$. I think this is pretty. Seriously, thanks you all that helped here. <3

Does the sequence $a_n$ have a closed form?  If not, how can you expect $c_n$ to have one?

You found closed forms for $c_0$, $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$, and similarly you can find a closed form for each $c_n$.  But that's not the same thing as saying that the sequence $c_n$ has a closed form.

@RobertIsrael, I wrote it wrong. I want a closed form for $c_n$ in terms of $a_n$. It's well related to Newton's formulas and Weierstrass's Factorization Theorem, which I was trying to get some result from (but I don't think I'll get any of that)

I saw that it can be expressed with the Bell polynomials, but I don't know how I get to it.

Isn't $c_1=-a_1$ and therefore expressions for $c_2$ and $c_3$ in the question must be fixed too?

Generating functions to the rescue! We set $f(x) = \sum_{n\geq0} c_n x^n$ and $g(x) = \sum_{n\geq0} a_{n+1} x^n$. Then
\begin{align}
f'(x)
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n c_n x^{n-1} = - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n c_{n-k}a_k  x^{n-1} \\
&= - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty  c_{n-k}a_k  x^{n-1} = - \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^{k-1} \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n \\
&= -g(x) f(x).
\end{align}
We reduced the problem to a differential equation with solution
$$
f(x) = \exp\left(- \int_0^x g(t) \text dt\right), 
$$
(because $c_0 = f(0) = 1$). Coefficients of $f$ can be expressed using Bell polynomials:
$$
c_n = \frac{1}{n!} B_n(-0! a_1, \ldots, -(n-1)! a_n) = \sum_{1i_1 + \ldots + ni_n = n} \prod_{j=1}^n \frac{(-a_j/j)^{i_j}}{i_j!}.
$$
The perfect example of this is the Gamma function
$$
\Gamma(x+1) = \exp\left(\int_0^x \psi(t+1) \text dt\right),
$$
where the digamma function $\psi$ can be written as
$$
\psi(x+1) = -\gamma - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \zeta(k+1) (-x)^k, 
$$
where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant and $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function. Therefore
$$
[x^n] \Gamma(x+1) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} B_n(\gamma, 1!\zeta(2), \ldots, (n-1)! \zeta(n)).
$$
The first few terms are
$$
\Gamma(x+1) = 1 - \gamma x + \left(\gamma^2 + \frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)\frac{x^2}{2} - \left(\gamma^3 + \frac{\gamma\pi^2}2 + 2 \zeta(3)\right)\frac{x^3}{6} + \ldots
$$
We could do someting similar to derive the power series for various exponents of the Gamma function.

What if $f(x) = g(x)$ ? Something Catalan like ?

In that case $c_n = a_{n+1}$ and $f(x) = 1/(1+x)$. This means that $c_n = (-1)^n$.

right thanks man

Thanks @Nolord, your answer is complete for me.

So if $a_n=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x_i^n}$, then $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n=\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{x}{x_n})$. A very cool result.

I wrote such MATLAB script that generates values of $c$ as polynomial expressions for me:
a = sym('a', [1 10]);
c = sym('c',[1 11]);

c(1) = 1;
for i = 2:11
    s = 0;
    for j = 1:(i-1)
        s = s + a(j) * c(i - j);
    end
    c(i) = expand(-1/(i-1) * s);
end

c

So the first values of $c_i$:
$c_0 = 1$
$c_1 = - a_1 = (-1)^1 \frac{1}{1!\cdot 1} a_1$
$c_2  = \frac{1}{2} a_1^2 - \frac{1}{2} a_2 = (-1)^2 \frac{1}{2!\cdot 1^2} a_1^2+(-1)^1 \frac{1}{1!\cdot 2} a_2$
$c_3 = -\frac{1}{6}a_1^3 + \frac{1}{2} a_1 a_2 - \frac{1}{3}a_3 = (-1)^3\frac{1}{3!\cdot 1^3}a_1^3+(-1)^2\frac{1}{1!\cdot 1!\cdot 1\cdot 2}a_1a_2 +(-1)^1\frac{1}{1!\cdot 3}a_3$
...
So, it's clear to me that the expressions for $c_n$ are clearly related to partitions of $n$ and their properties. I will search more to find names for stuff related to partitions (because I have no vocabulary to use here, it seems).
Proving that these obvious (?) properties of $c_n$ expressions hold is another thing, which I will try later if nobody else does it.

From zaa's observation, we can make by induction the sentence that $$c_n=\sum_{m_1+2m_2+3m_3+...+nm_n=n}\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{(-a_k)^{m_k}}{m_k!k^{m_k}}$$ where all $m_i\geq0$. I dont know if it can be proven but I think this is a
medium result.
